# no output from php script

Tags: php, html, validation

I have a `username` and `password` box and a `login` button. My `php` script should check if the boxes are empty and if the length of whats passed in is less than 6 characters. It is not doing what I want it to do and I am not sure why. I am new to php so I am using `W3 Schools` as reference but cant seem to figure out. I will past the code down below.

```
<?php

if($_POST){

#not empty
#atleast 6 characters long


# array holds errors
$errors = array();

# validation starts here
if(empty($_POST['uname'])){
    $errors['$uname1'] = "Your name cannot be empty";
}

if(strlen($_POST['uname']) < 6){
    $errors['uname2'] = "Must be longer than 6 characters";
}

if(empty($_POST['psw'])){
    $errors['psw1'] = "Your password cannot be empty";
}

if(strlen($_POST['psw']) < 6){
    $errors['psw2'] = "Must be longer than 6 characters";
}


if(count($errors) == 0){

    # redirect to the game page
    header('Location:success.html');
    exit();
}
}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Hangman Home Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <form action="" method="post" class="modal-content animate">



        <div class="container">
            </p>

            <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname">
            <p>
                <?php if(isset($errors['uname1'])) echo $errors['uname1'];  ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php if(isset($errors['uname2'])) echo $errors['uname2'];  ?>
            </p>


            <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw">
            <p>
                <?php if(isset($errors['psw1'])) echo $errors['psw1'];  ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php if(isset($errors['psw2'])) echo $errors['psw2'];  ?>
            </p>

            <button type="submit" value="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what behaviour do you expect, and what do you actually see?

Comment: The page just refreshes. I want to be able to see the message based on if they leave it blank or if it is less than a certain amount of characters.

Comment: Additionally, I suspect there may be issues with the form - for completeness you should also post the form HTML.

Comment: what do you mean the form HTML?

Comment: Sorry... I didn't scroll down. I see it's included. I ran your example on my machine - works fine.

Comment: but why is it that I cant see if the username or password is less than a certain amount of characters or if it is blank?

Comment: Don't know! Running your code on my own machine shows validation errors as expected - mostly. There's one error: `$errors['$uname1']` should be `$errors['uname1']`. Otherwise all validation errors are shown as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181847/discussion-between-moeeli-and-darragh-enright).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example. It's based on PHP7 feature called **null coalescing operator**. As [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) says:

> It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

So you can write something like this: `$uname = $_POST['uname'] ?? '';` which means `$uname` must be `$_POST['uname']` if `$_POST['uname']` exists and not equals to NULL. Otherwise it be equal to empty string `''`.

Same thing with echo error: `<?php echo $errors['psw'] ?? '';  ?>`. If error isset and not null - then echo them. Else echo empty string.

Also no need to check if string is empty. Because if string empty - that guarantee that string length less than 6.

```
<?php

$uname = $_POST['uname'] ?? '';
$psw = $_POST['psw'] ?? '';

$errors = [];

if(strlen($uname) < 6) $errors['uname'] = 'Name must be longer than 6 characters';
if(strlen($psw) < 6) $errors['psw'] = 'Password must be longer than 6 characters';

if(empty($errors)) {
    header('Location:success.html');
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Hangman Home Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <form action="" method="post" class="modal-content animate">



        <div class="container">
            </p>

            <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname">
            <p><?php echo $errors['uname'] ?? '';  ?></p>


            <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw">
            <p><?php echo $errors['psw'] ?? '';  ?></p>

            <button type="submit" value="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```